# ArrayList(XmlValueModel) move from one activity to another Activity

Tags: show

I am sending Arraylist one Activity to another but 2nd activity show null pointer and null adapter. how to fix it ??? thanks.

First Activity:

```
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("array_list", listdata);
        Intent movedata = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Shopping.class);
        movedata.putExtras(movedata);
        startActivity(movedata);
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        ArrayList<XmlValueModel> listdata = (ArrayList<XmlValueModel>) bundle.getSerializable("array_list");

  //     ArrayAdapter<XmlValueModel> array = new ArrayAdapter<XmlValueModel>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

       listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListOne);
       adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, listdata);
       listview.setAdapter(adapter);
   }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your XmlValueModel serialisable? You should implement the XmlValueModel with Serializable!

```
public class XmlValueModel implements Serializable {...}
```

In case the XmlValueModel comes from a library derive a new class from the XmlValueModel and implement Serializable.

Comment: Is your list non-null before putting it inside the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

**try this way may this help you**

**First you want to make**

**Class XmlValueModel implements Serializable**

```
public class XmlValueModel implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

**In your FirstActivity
do this way**

```
ArrayList<XmlValueModel> XmlValueModelArrayList = new ArrayList<XmlValueModel>();

Intent intent = new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("XmlValueModelArrayList", XmlValueModelArrayList);
```

**In your SecondActivity
do this way**

```
ArrayList<XmlValueModel> XmlValueModelList;

XmlValueModelList = (ArrayList<XmlValueModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
            "XmlValueModelArrayList");
```

Comment: Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<com.android.itcompany.XmlValueModel>......Which type of warning .... ?

Comment: as per my code ArrayList<VOclass> XmlValueModelList;